# Why do Django REST Framework builtin permission classes have request.user check?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm writing my first DRF project, and i was interested in how builtin DRF permission classes are implemented - `IsAuthenticated` and `IsAdminUser`, for example.

In `rest_framework/permissions.py` you can find following code:

```
class IsAdminUser(BasePermission):
    ...
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return bool(request.user and request.user.is_staff)

class IsAuthenticated(BasePermission):
    ...
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return bool(request.user and request.user.is_authenticated)
```

As you can see, both classes check for `request.user` before the second condition.
It is probably needed for some reason, but i can't figure out why.

The first thing that came to my mind was that `request.user` object might have `None` value or have some object without `is_staff` or `is_authenticated` attributes and in this case `request.user.is_staff` and `request.user.is_authenticated` will cause `AttributeError`.
I experimented a bit and even if i send unauthenticated request, `request.user` points to `AnonymousUser`. Same thing is written in docs:

> If no class authenticates, request.user will be set to an instance of
> django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser, and request.auth will be set
> to None.

But the most interesting thing here is that `AnonymousUser` object
actually has `is_staff` and `is_authenticated` attributes! Both are set to
`False`.
So why would you check for `request.user` first instead of directly checking `request.user.is_staff` and `request.user.is_authenticated` conditions?

Comment: It may be possible that someone has set `request.user` to `None` in some middleware or authentication backend. Can't hurt to handle this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.user` is a way to trigger all the authentication logic in django-rest-framework. This is a lazy property that must be accessed before attributes such as `request.user.is_authenticated` are available.

Relevant code in [django-rest-framework](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/request.py#L219-L228):

```py
class Request:
    …
    @property
    def user(self):
        """
        Returns the user associated with the current request, as authenticated
        by the authentication classes provided to the request.
        """
        if not hasattr(self, '_user'):
            with wrap_attributeerrors():
                self._authenticate()
        return self._user
```

As you can see, accessing the property triggers all the authentication logic, which is needed for the following permissions check to work.